# How can I close open UIAlertViews in iOS 7 when the app is about to suspend?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have this in my AppDelegate.m so that the app returns to the front page upon resuming:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

If this happens when a `UIAlertView` is open, it comes back to the root view with the alert open, and when I close it, the app crashes.

I'm wondering how I can in `applicationWillResignActive` close any modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my eventual solution was to follow the comment about `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` on the `UIAlertView` itself.

Every time I show one of these, I store the reference. Then in the `AppDelegate`, I do this:

```
if([SharedData singleton].m_currentModalView != nil)
{
    [(id)[SharedData singleton].m_currentModalView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
    [SharedData singleton].m_currentModalView = nil;
}
```

Also, it's good to remember to clear the reference when these are closed ordinarily by the user clicking a button. This is also working for `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: You adopt my solution but you don't accept or upvote it?

Comment: I didn't adopt your solution. I'm not using UIAlertController. Your answer doesn't cover iOS 7. I did upvote Antonio's, since it's very close to what I did. He's at zero because someone else downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will be a workaround;

- Subclass `UIAlertView`, use that class through all your app, and add objects of it as observer in `[NotificationCenter defaultCenter]`for some `fooNotification`.
- In `applicationWillBecomeActive:` post `fooNotification`
- In the handler selector of your custom `UIAlertView` dismiss the alert in some proper way.

Comment: There is no reason to post your own notification. Register for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.